# How can I diagnose network errors between my PC and Synology NAS

Tags: windows-10, nas, synology-diskstation, plex

I've got a Synology 215j NAS connected to my Windows 10 PC, and am running into some intermittent problems accessing the files on the NAS. I run Plex on the PC, with the media files on the NAS, and Plex will sometimes fail when recording TV shows via the Plex DVR. Troubleshooting on the Plex forums pointed to a network error; ProcMon showed errors similar to:

> 12:30:26.282  Plex Transcoder.exe WriteFile
> \MCubed\Media\Test.grab\e573a7ed0eaac332792ff0dac4892df0ce79c76f-fdd61eef7d6af2e5768e7de6f052911da4d06c55\Nature Cat (2015) - S03E03 - Onward and Songward; Why Did the Turtle Cross the Road.ts
> NETWORK ERROR
> Offset: 10,747,904, Length: 262,144, Priority: Normal

And a bunch of errors of type NETWORK ERROR:

[image: ProcMon log]

Anecdotally, I sometimes see it takes a "long" time to open files (Plex media, but also images, Word and Excel files, etc) on the NAS from the PC.

The Synology NAS is a DS215j, with 2x8TB WD Red HDDs (models WD80EFAX and WD80EFBX). The NAS itself is ~8 years old, with the drives being newer (3 and 2 years old, respectively). The two drives are set up in a single storage pool and volume (Synology hybrid raid), and there's about 1 TB of free space. It runs DSM  6.2.4-25556 Update 7. It is connected to the network via a Gigabit switch.

The Windows PC is custom-built, also ~8 years old. It is connected to the network via a Gigabit switch. I have two mapped network drives.

What could be causing the network errors seen in ProcMon and Plex, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Is this a new problem, or was it already happening for the last several years?

Comment: I don't remember when it started. Certainly been happening for the last few years (I don't know if it correlated with new drive(s)). I had Plex's transcoder directory set to the NAS and I recently changed it to a local SSD. That may have helped, but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Was there a time that this problem did NOT happen? Might the problem coincide with a change to the network, such as a new switch?

Comment: I don't recall a time when it didn't happen, but it may have been OK 3+ years ago. That was in a different house, though. It was mostly just a nuisance (shows would record with some skipping / pixelation in them), but it became a big problem in May of this year. After that, shows would record for 30 seconds or less and then stop - that's when I went to the Plex forums.

Comment: If the switches are fast enough and the connection is by direct ethernet cables, the problem might be with these cables regarding quality or too-large length, or environmental problems such as magnetic fields.

Comment: Cables are from monoprice, and a total of ~100ft between the PC and NAS. Some (~50ft) is in-wall, the rest are patch cables. One patch cable (25 or 50ft) is jumbled in a mess on the floor behind the PC, I'll swap that with a shorter one and see if that helps things

Comment: Put in a shorter cable and still see the same behavior.